# Expecting one more argument to ‘RedeemerType’

Tags: plutus, cardano-cli, smart-contract, haskell, marketing

My code is here

```
marketConstraints :: Market -> TxConstraints (RedeemerType -> ScriptContext -> Bool) (DatumType, ())
marketConstraints market = mustValidateIn (to $ scriptAddress market)
```

I am not sure how to do to correct this errors.

```
src/MarketState.hs:58:87: error:
   • Expecting one more argument to ‘RedeemerType’
      Expected a type, but ‘RedeemerType’ has kind ‘* -> *’
    • In the first argument of ‘TxConstraints’, namely
        ‘(RedeemerType -> ScriptContext -> Bool)’
      In the type signature:
        marketConstraints :: Market
                             -> TxConstraints (RedeemerType
                                               -> ScriptContext -> Bool) (DatumType, ())
   |
58 | marketConstraints :: Market -> TxConstraints (RedeemerType -> ScriptContext -> Bool) (DatumType, ())
   |                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^

src/MarketState.hs:58:87: error:
    • Expecting one more argument to ‘DatumType’
      Expected a type, but ‘DatumType’ has kind ‘* -> *’
    • In the second argument of ‘TxConstraints’, namely
        ‘(DatumType, ())’
      In the type signature:
        marketConstraints :: Market
                             -> TxConstraints (RedeemerType
                                               -> ScriptContext -> Bool) (DatumType, ())
```

Answer (score 0):

This is entirely related to Haskell. The kind of `(->)` is `* -> * -> *` thus in your type signature, both left-hand & right-hand side of `->` must have kind `*` but some of your parameters such as `RedeemerType` & `DatumType` are higher kinded. If you are new to all this "kind" jargon, I would suggest [this](https://diogocastro.com/blog/2018/10/17/haskells-kind-system-a-primer/) blog post on it.